Can I animate base64 images in an HTML file?
I have three images encoded as base64. I can display each of them in an HTML page using the following code (where ... denotes suppressed chars):
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBOR...SuQmCC" />

Can I create animation from these images, such that they are displayed in a loop on the same place in the page, each of them for e.g. 0.1 second?

For animatting and image referenced on base 64, you may:
In the HTML page:

define and image tag

In the style sheet:

Define the animation, put a background: url('data:image/png;base64, image code') for each frame
Reference that animation with the img tag as it is written below or as you would like



img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;

/*Specify your animation name and time*/

    animation-name: example2;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
/*Specify the images of your animation, you can tell how much time it's gonna last each image by writting the percentage from the beginning of the line*/
@keyframes example2 {
  0%   {background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...');}
  50%  {background: url('data:image/webp;base64,UklGRnAeAABXRU...');}
  100%  {background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE...');}
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>CSS Animation</h1>
<!--This image tag will be the one that will show the animation, if you want to put few, just write an id foreach and write it on the css -->
<img>

</body>
</html>



For more documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation2
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
